# Camel rest URI works with suffix

Tags: rest, apache-camel

So I have a REST webservice using Camel.

it works just fine except that if I call my URI with a suffix I get the same response and not a 404.

Rest Configuration:

```
restConfiguration()
.component("restlet")
.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json) 
.dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true") 
.contextPath(contextPath).host(host).port(port); 

rest("/ressource") .description("ressource")
.consumes("application/json") .produces("application/json") 
.get().outType(Ressource.class)
.to("bean:ressourceImpl?method=getRessource")
```

Example :

> localhost:8090/service/ressource
>
> returns my ressource
>
> localhost:8090/service/ressource85468461569
>
> returns my ressource

Is it normal ? I thought it should just return 404

Comment: how is your rest service configured?

Comment: restConfiguration().component("restlet").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
  .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
  .contextPath(contextPath).host(host).port(port);
  
  
  rest("/ressource")
  .description("ressource")
  .consumes("application/json")
  .produces("application/json")
  
  .get().outType(Ressource.class).to("bean:ressourceImpl?method=getRessource")

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: camel version 2.20.1

Comment: @ClausIbsen It looks like a bug.

Comment: This works with `netty4-http` component correctly. Only with `restlet` it looks like a bug. Change like this `restConfiguration().component("netty4-http")` and try

Comment: it works. Does changing from restlet to netty4-http have an impact on the app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is currently not supported.

I have logged a ticket to improve this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12320