# Rest query working for all suffix inputs after matching path in camel route

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, spring-rest, spring-camel

I have configured REST with Camel. In that I have successfully get response from writen APIs.
my problem is that given api works if i add anything after correct API string.

**camel route**

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
     rest("/say")
            .post("/bye").to("direct:byePost")   
        from("direct:byePost")
                .transform().constant("Bye(post) World");
}
```

**Configuration in web.xml**

```
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

From PostMan i am hitting below apis and getting shown results.

**Method:**  POST | http://localhost:8080/camel-rest/rest/say/bye
**Output:**  *Bye(post) World*

**Method:**  POST | http://localhost:8080/camel-rest/rest/say/bye/anything
**Output:**  *Bye(post) World*

**Method:**  POST | http://localhost:8080/camel-rest/rest/say/by?
**Output:**  *error: The server has not found anything matching the request URI*

**>> My question is why */say/bye/anything* is working even i have not listed anywhere in the route. any mistake i have done in route ?**

***>> why it is getting matched against 'rest/say/bye' ?***

Comment: check this out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070854/camel-rest-uri-works-with-suffix#comment85146996_49070854

Comment: @pvpkiran thanks for help. currently i m using 2.18.X and facing this problem.

Comment: ya. it is a bug with restlet component. It needs to be fixed in future releases. You can track the status of the big ticket created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12320. As if now it is still open. You cna change to other rest components  as mentioned in the comments section of that question